# Read in PHP Div value into a $variable and in Javascript read file names of uploaded files into array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a few questions:

Part 1: I have a `div` with the `id="hiddenID"`. I would like to create (if the sub folder does not exist) a subfolder with this id under the existing mainfolder `sobimages`.

And then to write the files in this new sub folder.

Note: Without the subfolder is it working!

Part 2: The uploaded files leave always the names and the success mnessage behind. I would like to delete this messages including the names of the uploaded files from the screen.

Part 3: Read before all file names in a simple Javascript array. I will then safe this with Json in the MySql-Databse. After your great help. I know how to do this, hehe

File `body_editarticles.php`

```
        <?php session_start();

            $_db_host = "myserver.com:3306";
            $_db_username = "admin0";
            $_db_passwort = "star1dgffh";
            $_db_datenbank = "sob";
            $_db_currentID ="";

            # Verbindung zur Datenbank herstellen
            $_link = mysql_connect($_db_host, $_db_username, $_db_passwort);

            # Pr�fen ob die Verbindung geklappt hat
            if (!$_link)
            {
                # Nein, also das ganze Skript abbrechen !
                die("Keine Verbindung zur Datenbank m�glich: " .
                    mysql_error());
            }

            # Datenbank ausw�hlen
            mysql_select_db($_db_datenbank, $_link);

        ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

        <head>

            <meta charset="UTF-8" />

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scroll.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>


        </head>

        <body class="page page-id-11505 page-template-default" onload="jsRecordCurrent();">

        <div id="page-wrap">

        <?php
        include('includes/header.html');
        ?>

        <div id="hiddenID" style="display: none;"></div>


        <div id="mulitplefileuploader" title="">
            <br>
            Upload
        </div>
        <div id="status"></div>

            <script>

            $(document).ready(function()
            {

                var settings = {
                    url: "upload.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif",
                    fileName: "myfile",
                    multiple: true,
                    onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
                    {
                        $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload successful</font>");
                    },
                    onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
                    {
                        $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload failed</font>");
                    }
                }
                $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);

            });

            </script>

        </div>

        </div>

        </div>

            <div id="aside">

            </div>

            <br class="clearfloat" />
        </div> <!-- End of main container -->

        </div><!-- END Page Wrap -->

        <div id="footer">
            <br class="clearfloat" />

        </div>

        </body>

        </html>
```

file "upload.php"

```
        <?php

        //If directory doesnot exists create it.
        $output_dir = "sobimages/";

        if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
        {
            $ret = array();

            $error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
            {

                if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) //single file
                {
                    $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
                    //echo "<br> Error: ".$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];

                    $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$fileName;
                }
                else
                {
                    $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]['name']);
                    for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
                    {
                        $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
                        $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$fileName;
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$fileName );
                    }

                }
            }
            echo json_encode($ret);

        }
```

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` libraries; use PDO / MySQLi instead. Also, time to learn new HTML coding style.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mkdir to create folders and subfolders recursively before writing the files:

```
mkdir($path, 0777, true);
```

Note the third parameter, which means **recursive**

See the mkdir docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: Thank you for the answers. How can I add to the existing data in ajax the data from the hidden field?

Answer (score 0):

1) send hiddenID value to ajax call

like var hiddenID = $("#hiddenID").val();

pass this id to ajax call, in PHP page you can get like $_POST['hiddenID];

then make a directory using the $_POST['hiddenID] using mkdir function (mkdir($pathtocreate, 0777, true);)

3) to read file names.....
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Thank you for this idea with the hiddenID. Can you show me how I add this hiddenID tot the already existing data in ajax?

And how to read it then out in the upload.php file

That would be very nice. I am on the end of my ideas ...

Comment: take a field like <input type="hidden" value="which we need to send to ajax call " id = "hiddenID "/> then get the value using jquery like $("#hiddenID").val();